# Finding minimum and maximum values of the first column - grouped by the second column

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have lots of unsorted data in text file in the following form:

```
1.0 10
1.8 10
1.1 10
1.9 20
2.8 20
2.1 20
2.9 20
...
```

For each value in the second column, I want to get the interval of values in the first column. So for the example above, the result should be

```
1.0 1.8 10
1.9 2.9 20
```

How can I do this with c/c++, awk or other linux shell tools?

Comment: The question should be clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '{
        if (!($2 in nmin) || $1<nmin[$2])
            nmin[$2]=$1;
         else if ($1>=nmax[$2])
            nmax[$2]=$1
     }
     END {
        for (a in nmin)
           print nmin[a], nmax[a], a
     }
' inFile
```

Comment: minor modified:{
 if (!($2 in nmin) || $1<nmin[$2])
  nmin[$2]=$1;
 else if ($1>=nmax[$2])
  nmax[$2]=$1;
}
END{
 for (a in nmin){
  if(!nmax[a])
   print nmin[a], nmin[a], a;
  else 
   print nmin[a], nmax[a], a;
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner should work for you:

```
 awk '!($2 in i){i[$2]=$1}{a[$2]=$1}END{for(x in i)print i[x],a[x],x}' file
```

output:

```
1.0 1.8 10
1.9 2.9 20
```

Comment: @Dong Just fyi that it will work fine with the your current input (already sorted). However if input isn't already sorted then it won't work.

Comment: Right, so data should be sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
{ read vStart int &&
while read vNext nextInt; do
  if [ $int -ne $nextInt ]; then
    echo "$vStart $v $int";
    vStart=$vNext;
  fi

  v=$vNext;
  int=$nextInt;
done &&
echo "$vStart $v $int"; }
```

Comment: @Dong: right, but in the original question the input set was already sorted (accidentally?)

Answer (score 0):

To add another alternative, you could do this in R as well:

```
d.in <- read.table(file = commandArgs(trailingOnly = T)[1]);
write.table(
    aggregate(V1 ~ V2, d.in, function (x) c(min(x),max(x)))[,c(2,1)]
    , row.names = F
    , col.names = F
    , sep = "\t");
```

Then just call this script with `Rscript`:

```
$ Rscript script.R data.txt 
1       1.8     10
1.9     2.9     20
```